# Update subobject in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

This is what I have in my db.

```
{     
    "_id": { "$oid" : "1111" },
    "gallery": {
        "images": [
        {
            "image": "test1.jpg",
            "_id": { "$oid" : "1111a" }
        },
        {
            "image": "test2.jpg",
            "_id": { "$oid" : "1111b" }
        },
        {
            "image": "test3.jpg",
            "_id": { "$oid" : "1111c" }
        }
      ]
    }
}
,{     
    "_id": { "$oid" : "2222" },
    "gallery": {
        "images": [
        {
            "image": "test1.jpg",
            "_id": { "$oid" : "2222a" }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I would like to update the second element (image:"test2.jpg") of the first element (_id:"1111").
The result should be

```
        ...
        {
            "image": "test2new.jpg",
            "_id": { "$oid" : "1111b" }
        },
        ...
```

I have the _id of the second image "1111b".
How can I do it?

**UPDATE**
I tried this query, but it doesn't work.

```
{ 
    '_id':{'$oid' : '1111' }
   ,'gallery.image': $elemMatch:{ '_id':{'$oid':'1111b' } }
}
,{ 
    $set:{ 'gallery.images.$.image':'test2new.jpg' }
}
```

**SOLUTION**
_id without quotes and without add { "$oid" :

```
{ 
    { _id : '1111' }
   ,{ 'gallery.image': $elemMatch:{ _id:'1111b' } }
}
,{ 
    $set:{ 'gallery.images.$.image':'test2new.jpg' }
}
```

Comment: What did you try? (C)

Comment: It was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247007/mongodb-update-the-specific-element-from-subarray

Comment: Thanks, I saw that post but it's a bit different because I have this kind of id     "_id": { "$oid" : "1111b" }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the $ operator with update.Assuming your collection is named images you can use the following query:

```
db.images.update({'_id.oid':'1111','gallery.images':{'$elemMatch':{'image':'test2.jpg'}}},{'$set':{'gallery.images.$.image':'test2new.jpg'}})
```

You can read more about it here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-a-document-element-without-specifying-its-position

Comment: ok, I found the problem... It works fine on server/browser. But the query doesn't work on MondoHub...
anyway... I update with my solution :)